# PL/SQL: Exclamation Mark in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

What are those exclamation(!) marks in the following query?

```
l_sql := q'!
              SELECT CASE WHEN FILTER_CNT = 0 THEN NULL ELSE FILTER_LIST END AS FILTER_LIST
              FROM
              (
                  SELECT 'TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE ' || LISTAGG(''''||EXCLUSION_CRITERIA||'''', ' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS FILTER_LIST, COUNT(*) AS FILTER_CNT
                  FROM !'|| p_after_owner ||q'!.UT_TABLE_EXCLUSION
                  WHERE EXCLUSION_TYPE = 'P'
              )
            !';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `q` method of quoting strings means that you don't have to escape single quotes in the string.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218), it works like this:

```
q'<single character delimiter><text><single character delimiter>'
```

Therefore, the `!`s in your sample string are acting as the quote delimiter.

For example, if you want to use the string `Don't worry, be happy`, in the old style quoting, that would become:

```
'Don''t worry, be happy'
```

but the new quoting mechanism would be:

```
q'!Don't worry, be happy!'
```

or

```
q'{Don't worry, be happy}'
```

etc.